# Angular Reactive Forms validation date year four digits

Tags: regex, angular, date, angular-reactive-forms

I use Angular Reactive Forms and I want valid the format of my date in priority (before the two existing validators). My valid format is dd/MM/YYYY (**not** dd/MM/YY). I use a bootstrap v4 date picker.

**My form:**

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  'day': ['', [Validators.required, minDateValidator(this.todayMoment.toDate()), businessDayValidator()]]
});
```

My validators:

```
export function minDateValidator(minDate: Date): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const invalid = control.value < minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0);
    return invalid ? {'minDate': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}

export function businessDayValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const invalid = !DateUtilsService.isBusinessDay(moment(control.value));
    return invalid ? {'businessDay': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

I try add this `Validators.pattern('(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[2-9]{2}.*')`

[online regex exec](https://regex101.com/r/9BmZ3Q/1) is OK but not in Angular (print this error):

```
{ "pattern": { "requiredPattern": "^(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[2-9]{2}.*$", "actualValue": "2019-04-15T10:00:00.000Z" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in bootstrap datepicker is "the value is a date not a string".

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  'day': ['', [Validators.required, formatValidator(), minDateValidator(this.todayMoment.toDate()), businessDayValidator()]]
});

export function formatValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const dateRegEx = new RegExp('^(2|1){1}[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.*$');
    const dateInput = control.value as Date;
    const match = dateInput.toISOString && dateRegEx.test(dateInput.toISOString());
    return  match ? null : {'formatValidator': {value: control.value} };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass pattern as a regex instead of string, like this: Validators.pattern(/^(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[2-9]{2}.*/)

Comment: I have same error: `{ "pattern": { "requiredPattern": "/^(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[2-9]{2}.*/", "actualValue": "2019-04-15T10:00:00.000Z" } }`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the ending $ in my answer; try this one Validators.pattern(/^(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*$/)

Comment: I update regexp and I have same error: `{ "pattern": { "requiredPattern": "/^(2|1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*$/", "actualValue": "2019-04-15T10:00:00.000Z" } }`